# IOS Weird compiler error: "expected ']' before ;' using set-ter for NSString constant in singleton

Tags: ios, sdk, nsstring, singleton, constants

I have the weirdest error!  In Xcode I have a singleton with the following defined (file is: `MyGizmoClass.h`):

```
NSString            *plistPath;

NSString            *dataDomain;
NSString            *pathToChatScript;
NSString            *pathToUpdates;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *plistPath;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *dataDomain;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *pathToChatScript;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *pathToUpdates;
```

I have a `Constants.h` file (which I `#import` early in my .pch file) that contains:

```
#define kUserPlistName  @"userPlist.plist"

#define kDataDomain @"http://www.jann.com/";
#define kPathToChatScript @"path/top/chatscript.cgi";
#define kPathToupdates @"pathtoupdates/";
```

Okay, so far, so good.

The order, in my .pch file is as such:

```
#import "Constants.h"
#import "MyGizmoClass.h"
```

and then later in the `Constants.h` file I do this:

```
#import "FileFunctions.h"
```

Okay, fine setup.  This should work, a singleton with 3 NSStrings.  But when I try to do this in `FileFunctions.h` I get a weird error in the compiler:

`FileFunctions.h`

```
[myGizmoClass setDataDomain: kDataDomain];
[myGizmoClass setPathToChatScript: kPathToChatScript];
[myGizmoClass setPathToUpdates: kPathToupdates];

[myGizmoClass setPlistPath:[[myGizmoClass libraryDir]  stringByAppendingPathComponent:kUserPlistName]];
```

> **Compiler Results**
>
> Expected ']' before ;

What is going on?  I get this 3 times ... one for setDataDomain, one for setPathToChatScript and one for setPathToUpdates.  But no error on `kUserPlistName`.  When I do this in `FileFunctions.h` then all is well:

```
[myGizmoClass setDataDomain: @"http://www.jann.com/"];
[myGizmoClass setPathToChatScript: @"path/top/chatscript.cgi"];
[myGizmoClass setPathToUpdates: @"pathtoupdates/"];
```

> **Compiler Results**
>
> All is well.

I cannot figure this out.  Later (4 lines below this) I do the following:

```
[myGizmoClass setPlistPath:[[myGizmoClass libraryDir]  stringByAppendingPathComponent:kUserPlistName]];
```

And **THAT** works!  Why would subbing `kUserPlistName` work, yet `kDataDomain` wouldn't?  This is probably SO easy...but I cannot, for the life of me, see it!

**ADDENDUM**

I have found that EVERYWHERE I use `kDataDomain`, `setPathToChatScript` or `setPathToUpdates` in the code I get the same

> **Compiler Results**
>
> Expected ']' before ;

error!  :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't include the semicolon in  your `#define`s.

The compiler substitutes in exactly what you have there, so these would be equivalent:

```
[myGizmoClass setPathToUpdates: kPathToupdates];
[myGizmoClass setPathToUpdates: @"pathtoupdates/";]; // obvious syntax error
```

Comment: OMGosh!  I did not see that!  You know sometimes you cannot see the forest for the trees!  Thanks @jtbandes!  I really appreciate you being my eyes!  Will accept answer in 6 minutes (this "have to wait xyz minutes" to accept what is obviously a correct answer is irritating!)